# How to upgrade gcc 4.7.2 in centos 6.9 to gcc 4.8

Tags: gcc, centos, redhat, centos6, yum

I am running centos version 6.9 and had installed gcc using command `sudo yum install -y gcc gcc-c++` which installed gcc version 4.7.2. However i need to use gcc version 4.8.5. How do i upgrade gcc to the required version?

Answer (score 1):

CentOS 6 does not come with GCC 4.7, so you must have installed something else.

You can upgrade to CentOS 7.  This will give you GCC 4.8.5 (plus extensive backports, including at least one new backend).  But the binaries you compile on CentOS 7 will not run on CentOS 6.

If you need just a newer GCC, and not version 4.8.5 exactly, you can use [Developer Toolset](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-7/).  Version 7 gives you GCC 7.  For C and C++ at least, the compiled code will run on any CentOS 6 system.